# Can't read my table

Tags: tables, multirow, multicolumn, overleaf

Trying to print this table in one page or two maybe .
 please help.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[margin=2in]{geometry}  %use this later of you need tp specfy margin
%\usepackage{microtype} % might not be helpful
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{comment}
\excludecomment{comment}
%\includecomment{comment}
\usepackage{graphicx} % for grapghics
\usepackage{caption}  % Enable figure captions or figure notes
\usepackage{subcaption} %Further enable subcaptions
\usepackage{booktabs} %for table
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath} %for equations and mathematical symbols
\usepackage{rotating} %for table rotation
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{float} % allow tables to self adjust
\usepackage{morefloats}
%\usepackage{booktabs,caption,fixltx2e}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{hyperref} % allow hyper referencing
\usepackage{breakcites}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{amssymb} % for mathmatical symbols
\usepackage{enumerate} % to get all that enumeration offers
\usepackage{xcolor} % for font coloring
\captionsetup{font=footnotesize}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}[ht]
\centering
\caption{Empirical Analysis comparing DY, GHD, SVS}
\label{tab1}
\begin{adjustbox}{width=1\textwidth}
    \large
\begin{tabular}{@{}llll@{}}
\toprule

\multicolumn{4}{c}{Transmission}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       \\ \midrule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Blocks} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{DY}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        & \multicolumn{1}{c}{GHD}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           & \multicolumn{1}{c}{GHD-SVD}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           \\
\multirow{5}{*}{AC}        & 1.  Transmission mounts for India, Singapore and Thailand facing GFC.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         & 1. Patterns accord well with DY results for India, Singapore and Thailand during 2006-2008 GFC period.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            & \multirow{5}{*}{Transmissions in the AC cluster evince  effects of contagion swaying the markets.}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           \\
                           & 2. South Korean transmissions amplify during 2002-2004, when then global economy was riddled with many crises.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                & 2. As opposed to DY depiction, South Korean transmission bears negetive sign suggesting, dampening of transmission is dominant during 2002-2004.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       \\
                           & 3. Malaysia and the Philippines markets demonstrates neutral to dampening transmissions all around.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           & \multirow{2}{*}{3. The Phillipines and South Korea portrays negetive transmissions , with the only exception during the GFC event. This supports DY argument.}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       \\
                           & 4. Inclusion of oil and commodity indices amplifies transmission during crisis, only for India and South Korea.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       \\
                           & 5. Little amplification in transmission is observed for all participants facincg GFC.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         & 4. Positive transmissions are plotted for all markets during GFC, similar to the DY observations.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       \\
EC                         & 1. We find a resurgance in transmission for Germany during 2002-2004  similar to that of South Korea mentioned earlier.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       & 1.  Again,  with Germany we find negetive transmissions across 2002-2004, rejecting DY depiction.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 & \multirow{2}{*}{1. Results remain consistent with GHD, with contagion prevailing for Germany, France, UK markets.}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    \\
\multirow{3}{*}{}          & 2. France and UK transmissions amplify in the advent of Eurozone crisis, while remaining neutral in th earlier crises.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        & 2. Consistent with DY, GHD shows positive transmission across Eurozone crisis, precedeed by a negetive dampening during GFC for both France and UK.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       \\
                           & 3. Australian transmissions slightly amplify during GFC and  during Export crisis. Dampenings prevails in the transitions between crises.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     & 3. GHD is consistent with DY for Australia                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        & \multirow{2}{*}{2. Short-lived volatility rises profoundly for Australia and China corresponding to major events. This explains Australian and Chinese transmissions are driven predominantly .}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               \\
                           & 4.  Chinese transmissions amplify mostly with the recent Chinese crisis. Earlier, Chinese transmissions amplified only during GFC.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            & 4. The findings are in accord with DY.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       \\
\multirow{3}{*}{GC}        & 1. Transmissions amplify for Greece, Portugal and Ireland with the Eurozone crisis /GC. Recently, Ireland transmissions ascend following a descend.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           & 1. Greek transmission evinces small surges in the positive direction, followed by strong negetive dampenings.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                & \multirow{3}{*}{Clustered volatility spawning out of high risk premia explains high transmissions with short-lived connections for Potugal and Belgium, mostly during GFC and not the Eurozone crisis period.}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        \\
                           & \multirow{2}{*}{2. Belgium shows escalating transmissions facing the recent export shrinkage.}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                & 2. Belgium transmissions remain neutral to dampening. Unlike DY, the postive and negetive estimates offset strong amplifications for Belgium.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       \\
                           &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               & 3. As the Greek crisis unfolds, positive transmissions resurge for Croatia. This is not identified with DY.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       \\
\multirow{4}{*}{OED}       & 1. We find the strongest transmissions for the USA and Japan during dot comm bubble. studies in this tenet, is dismissed with GHD. & \multirow{4}{*}{Of all the markets presented in this block, high volatility in transmissions holds sway over Japan and New Zealand only. Crucially, this explains `conduit' transmissions for Japan, s are volatility driven simply due to its high  susceptability to debeloped markets and oil shocks.} \\
                           & 2. Russian trasmissions amplify in all major events across the sample periods, leading to a phenomenal jump facing the recent Russian financial crisis of 2014-2015. Inclusion of oil and commodity indices slightly dampen the transmissions.                                                                                                                                                                & 2. Risk transmission from Russia remains strongly positive for the most part, with exceptions only during the advent of GFC and Russian Crisis 2014-2015.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       \\
                           & 3.  The transmissions for both Canada and Norway  sharply descends corresponding to                                                                                                                               & 3. The patterns accord well with the DY findings for both Canada and Norway. Additionally,                                                                                                                                                                                      &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       \\
                           & 4. Gyrations in the transmissions of New Zealand do not show sharp occiliations.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              & 4. For the most part, the transmissions that New Zealand emit is near to its mean, t.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       \\ \cmidrule(lr){2-3}


\end{tabular}
 \end{adjustbox}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What is the problem, exactly?

Comment: Please clean up your MWE, deleting `\usepackage` commands that are not needed for its purpose. To have your table on two pages, you may need the `longtable` package.

Comment: Your table is very huge. For it placement you need two pages. consequently it should be written as `longtable` or as `ltablex`, both in landscape orientation. cannot be in

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a possibility with the `xltabular` package, which makes tabularx breakable over pages. This requires changing `sidewaystable`to `landscape` environment.

Unrelated: with recent versions of LaTex, you don't have to load `fixltx2e` anymore. Also, never use `adjustbox` with tables: it leads to inconsistent font sizes and most of the time makes them unreadable.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[margin=2in]{geometry} %use this later of you need tp specify margin
%\usepackage{microtype} % might not be helpful
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{comment}
\excludecomment{comment}
%\includecomment{comment}
\usepackage{graphicx} % for graphics
\usepackage{caption} % Enable figure captions or figure notes
\usepackage{subcaption} %Further enable subcaptions
\usepackage{booktabs} %for table
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath} %for equations and mathematical symbols
\usepackage{rotating} %for table rotation
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{float} % allow tables to self adjust
\usepackage{morefloats}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{tabularx, xltabular}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{breakcites}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{amssymb} % for mathematical symbols
\usepackage{enumerate} % to get all that enumeration offers
\usepackage{xcolor} % for font coloring
\captionsetup{font=footnotesize}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref} % allow hyper referencing

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}%
\centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{@{}lXX>{\arraybackslash}X@{}}
\caption{Empirical Analysis comparing DY, GHD, SVS}
\label{tab1} \\
\toprule
\multicolumn{4}{c}{Transmission} \\ \midrule
{Blocks} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{DY} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{GHD} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{GHD-SVD} \\[1ex]
{AC} & 1. Transmission mounts for India, Singapore and Thailand facing GFC. & 1. Patterns accord well with DY results for India, Singapore and Thailand during 2006-2008 GFC period. & \multirow{16}{=}{Transmissions in the AC cluster evince effects of contagion swaying the markets.} \\
                           & 2. South Korean transmissions amplify during 2002-2004, when then global economy was riddled with many crises. & 2. As opposed to DY depiction, South Korean transmission bears negative sign suggesting, dampening of transmission is dominant during 2002-2004. & \\
                           & 3. Malaysia and the Philippines markets demonstrates neutral to dampening transmissions all around. & \multirow{2}{=}{3. The Philippines and South Korea portrays negative transmissions , with the only exception during the GFC event. This supports DY argument.} & \\
                           & 4. Inclusion of oil and commodity indices amplifies transmission during crisis, only for India and South Korea. & & \\
                           & 5. Little amplification in transmission is observed for all participants facing GFC. & 4. Positive transmissions are plotted for all markets during GFC, similar to the DY observations. & \\
\addlinespace[2ex]
EC & 1. We find a resurgence in transmission for Germany during 2002-2004 similar to that of South Korea mentioned earlier. & 1. Again, with Germany we find negative transmissions across 2002-2004, rejecting DY depiction. & \multirow{2}{=}{1. Results remain consistent with GHD, with contagion prevailing for Germany, France, UK markets.} \\
 & 2. France and UK transmissions amplify in the advent of Eurozone crisis, while remaining neutral in th earlier crises. & 2. Consistent with DY, GHD shows positive transmission across Eurozone crisis, preceded by a negative dampening during GFC for both France and UK. & \\
                           & 3. Australian transmissions slightly amplify during GFC and during Export crisis. Dampenings prevails in the transitions between crises. & 3. GHD is consistent with DY for Australia & \multirow{2} {=}{2. Short-lived volatility rises profoundly for Australia and China corresponding to major events. This explains Australian and Chinese transmissions are driven predominantly .} \\
                           & 4. Chinese transmissions amplify mostly with the recent Chinese crisis. Earlier, Chinese transmissions amplified only during GFC. & 4. The findings are in accord with DY. & \\
\addlinespace[2ex]
{GC} & 1. Transmissions amplify for Greece, Portugal and Ireland with the Eurozone crisis /GC. Recently, Ireland transmissions ascend following a descend. & 1. Greek transmission evinces small surges in the positive direction, followed by strong negative dampenings. & \multirow{3}{=}{Clustered volatility spawning out of high risk premia explains high transmissions with short-lived connections for Portugal and Belgium, mostly during GFC and not the Eurozone crisis period.} \\
                           & \multirow{2}{=}{2. Belgium shows escalating transmissions facing the recent export shrinkage.} & 2. Belgium transmissions remain neutral to dampening. Unlike DY, the positive and negative estimates offset strong amplifications for Belgium. & \\
                           & & 3. As the Greek crisis unfolds, positive transmissions resurge for Croatia. This is not identified with DY. & \\
%%
\addlinespace[2ex]
{OED} & 1. We find the strongest transmissions for the USA and Japan during dot comm bubble. studies in this tenet, is dismissed with GHD. &{Of all the markets presented in this block, high volatility in transmissions holds sway over Japan and New Zealand only. Crucially, this explains `conduit' transmissions for Japan, s are volatility driven simply due to its high susceptability to developed markets and oil shocks.} \\% \multirow{14}{=}
  & 2. Russian transmissions amplify in all major events across the sample periods, leading to a phenomenal jump facing the recent Russian financial crisis of 2014-2015. Inclusion of oil and commodity indices slightly dampen the transmissions. & 2. Risk transmission from Russia remains strongly positive for the most part, with exceptions only during the advent of GFC and Russian Crisis 2014-2015. & \\
 & 3. The transmissions for both Canada and Norway sharply descends corresponding to & 3. The patterns accord well with the DY findings for both Canada and Norway. Additionally, & \\
 & 4. Gyrations in the transmissions of New Zealand do not show sharp oscillations. & 4. For the most part, the transmissions that New Zealand emit is near to its mean, t. & \\ \cmidrule(lr){2-3}

\end{xltabular}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I have come to a solution that looks very similar to Bernard but uses a different approach.

I included the `enumerate` environment inside the `longtable` cell so you don't waste time numbering. Similarly I rotated the page instead of the table.

As your code is very extensive and weirdly layout I did not copy the whole content, just part of if so you can have an idea and tweak it yourself.

[image: Enumerate inside a longtable]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs} %for table
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{pdflscape} %turn the page
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{leftmargin=*,}
\setlist{nosep,before=\vspace{-\baselineskip}}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\begin{longtable}{cp{7.5cm}p{7.5cm}p{7.5cm}}
%\begin{tabularx}{23cm}{m{2em}m{7cm}m{7cm}X}
\toprule
\multicolumn{4}{c}{Transmission}   \\
\midrule
Blocks &\centering DY & \centering GHD & \multicolumn{1}{c}{GHD-SVD} \\ %both solutions works
\midrule
{AC} & \begin{enumerate}\item Transmission mounts for India, Singapore and Thailand facing GFC.
\item South Korean transmissions amplify during 2002-2004, when then global economy was riddled with many crises.
\item Malaysia and the Philippines markets demonstrates neutral to dampening transmissions all around.
\item Inclusion of oil and commodity indices amplies transmission during crisis, only for India and South Korea.
\item Little amplication in transmission is observed for all participants facincg GFC.
\end{enumerate}
& 
\begin{enumerate}
\item Patterns accord well with DY results for India, Singapore and Thailand during 2006-2008 GFC period.
\item As opposed to DY depiction, South Korean transmission bears negetive sign suggesting, dampening of transmission is dominant during 2002-2004.
\end{enumerate}
  & 
 \medskip %cheating

  Transmissions in the AC cluster evince  effects of contagion swaying the markets. 
   \\
   \midrule 
EC & \begin{enumerate}
\item The rest of your text.
\item The rest of your text.
\end{enumerate}  &  &  \\
\midrule 
GC &  &  &  \\
\midrule 
OED &  &  &  \\
\bottomrule
%\end{tabularx} 
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: G. Bay, I am getting this error, " Overfull \hbox (50.28482pt too wide) in alignment in lines 16 --56 ...how to control this?

Answer (score 2):

With `ltablex`, `enumitem`, font size `\small`, with table headers on each page and with only necessary part of preamble for this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs, ltablex}
\keepXColumns
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}

\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
    \small
\setlist[enumerate]{nosep,
                    wide,
                    label=\textbf{\arabic*}.,
                    before = \vspace{-\baselineskip},
                    after  = \vspace{-\baselineskip}
                    }
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}lXXX@{}}
\caption{Empirical Analysis comparing DY, GHD, SVS}
\label{tab1}
    \\  \toprule
\multicolumn{4}{c}{Transmission}
    \\ \midrule
\mc{Blocks} &   \mc{DY} &   \mc{GHD}    & \mc{GHD-SVD}
    \\
\endfirsthead
\caption*{Table~\thetable: Empirical Analysis comparing DY, GHD, SVS}
\label{tab1}    \\
    \toprule
\multicolumn{4}{c}{Transmission}
    \\ \midrule
\mc{Blocks} &   \mc{DY} &   \mc{GHD}    & \mc{GHD-SVD}
    \\
\endhead
    \midrule
\multicolumn{4}{r}{\textit{continue on the next page}}
\endfoot
    \bottomrule
\endlastfoot
AC  &   \begin{enumerate}
    \item   Transmission mounts for India, Singapore and Thailand facing GFC.
    \item   South Korean transmissions amplify during 2002-2004, when then global economy was riddled with many crises.
    \item   Malaysia and the Philippines markets demonstrates neutral to dampening transmissions all around.
    \item   Inclusion of oil and commodity indices amplifies transmission during crisis, only for India and South Korea.
    \item   Little amplification in transmission is observed for all participants facincg GFC.
    \end{enumerate}
        &   \begin{enumerate}
        \item   Patterns accord well with DY results for India, Singapore and Thailand during 2006-2008 GFC period.
        \item   As opposed to DY depiction, South Korean transmission bears negetive sign suggesting, dampening of transmission is dominant during 2002-2004.
        \item   The Philippines and South Korea portrays negative transmissions , with the only exception during the GFC event. This supports DY argument.
        \item   Positive transmissions are plotted for all markets during GFC, similar to the DY observations
            \end{enumerate}
            &   Transmissions in the AC cluster evince  effects of contagion swaying the markets.
    \\  \addlinespace
EC  &   \begin{enumerate}
    \item   We find a resurgence in transmission for Germany during 2002-2004  similar to that of South Korea mentioned earlier.
    \item   France and UK transmissions amplify in the advent of Eurozone crisis, while remaining neutral in th earlier crises.
    \item   Australian transmissions slightly amplify during GFC and  during Export crisis. Dampening prevails in the transitions between crises.
    \item   Chinese transmissions amplify mostly with the recent Chinese crisis. Earlier, Chinese transmissions amplified only during GFC.
        \end{enumerate}
        &   \begin{enumerate}
        \item   Again,  with Germany we find negative transmissions across 2002-2004, rejecting DY depiction.
        \item   Consistent with DY, GHD shows positive transmission across Eurozone crisis, preceded by a negative dampening during GFC for both France and UK.
        \item   GHD is consistent with DY for Australia .
        \item   The findings are in accord with DY.
            \end{enumerate}
            &   \begin{enumerate}
            \item   Results remain consistent with GHD, with contagion prevailing for Germany, France, UK markets.
            \item   Short-lived volatility rises profoundly for Australia and China corresponding to major events. This explains Australian and Chinese transmissions are driven predominantly .
                \end{enumerate}
    \\  \addlinespace
GC  &   \begin{enumerate}
    \item   Transmissions amplify for Greece, Portugal and Ireland with the Eurozone crisis /GC. Recently, Ireland transmissions ascend following a descend.
    \item   Belgium shows escalating transmissions facing the recent export shrinkage.
        \end{enumerate}
        &   \begin{enumerate}
        \item   Greek transmission evinces small surges in the positive direction, followed by strong negative dampening.
        \item   Belgium transmissions remain neutral to dampening. Unlike DY, the positive and negative estimates offset strong amplifications for Belgium.
        \item   As the Greek crisis unfolds, positive transmissions resurge for Croatia. This is not identified with DY.
            \end{enumerate}
    \\  \addlinespace
OED &   \begin{enumerate}
    \item   We find the strongest transmissions for the USA and Japan during dot comm bubble. studies in this tenet, is dismissed with GHD.
    \item    Russian transmissions amplify in all major events across the sample periods, leading to a phenomenal jump facing the recent Russian financial crisis of 2014-2015. Inclusion of oil and commodity indices slightly dampen the transmissions.
    \item   The transmissions for both Canada and Norway  sharply descends corresponding to
    \item   Gyrations in the transmissions of New Zealand do not show sharp oscillations.
        \end{enumerate}
        &   \begin{enumerate}
        \item   Of all the markets presented in this block, high volatility in transmissions holds sway over Japan and New Zealand only. Crucially, this explains `conduit' transmissions for Japan, s are volatility driven simply due to its high  susceptibility to developed markets and oil shocks.
        \item   Risk transmission from Russia remains strongly positive for the most part, with exceptions only during the advent of GFC and Russian Crisis 2014-2015.
        \item   The patterns accord well with the DY findings for both Canada and Norway. Additionally, ...
        \item   For the most part, the transmissions that New Zealand emit is near to its mean, ...
        \end{enumerate}
            &
    \\
    \end{tabularx}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: I have another problem. I am using \documentclass[12pt,english]{article}. But the table here breaks into small pieced with 12pt. It s fine when \documentclass{article}. I am putting this table within the body of \documentclass[12pt,english]{article}, but i want the default size  that comes with \documentclass{article} only for the table. The fonts outside the table has bigger size but within landscape they should revert to default size. Can you help please?

Comment: @R.Islam, but you selected another answer (again), so i expect that new request you will address to its author. you can also ask new question regardless that reducing font size  for table (if i understand you correctly) should not be big deal.

Comment: Hi Zerko, no I moved my table to the format you suggested.on february 7 i posted that in the comments, you will find it scrolling up. you can find that in a new question https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/474626/148104. And that is why i addressed the question to you/

Comment: I need your help on fixing the table. the detail is posted in tex.stackexchange.com/q/474626/148104. I will appreciate your kind suggestion

Comment: well, you select another answer and than you use in your documents my answer. sorry, but i'm confuse. why you not use selected answer?